# Parsing User Input, string comparison

Tags: c, string, parsing

In my function, I want to check to see if the C-style string parameter being passed in meets certain conditions. If the user enters "I/P" the compiler always thinks I'm wanting to process "I"... The same goes for if the user enters "DNA" the compiler stops thinking "D" was input... How can I do I fix this?

```
     void parseUserInput(char *userInput)
    {
           if (strncmp(userInput, "D", 1) == 0)
        {
                printf(">> This input should be directed to the << assessGrade(char *) >> function ...\n");
                assessGrade(userInput);
        }
            else if (strncmp(userInput, "I", 1) == 0)
        {
                printf("Student has Special Situation : I (Incomplete)\n");
        }
            else if (strncmp(userInput, "I/P", 3) == 0)
        {
                printf("Student has Special Situation : I/P (In Process)\n");
        }
           else if (strncmp(userInput, "DNA", 3) == 0)
        {
               printf("Student has Special Situation : DNA (Did Not Attend)\n");
    }
```

Comment: Change the order of the checks? More specific checks should go first.

Comment: @kaylum Now say reorder, I still have other checks such as "AU" , "A+", and "A", and after reordering I still run into that problem

Comment: You won't have a problem if you do it correctly. Please provide exact details if you think you still do.

Comment: Put longer comparison more front.

Comment: @kaylum I feel dumb, thank you very much, I reordered correctly and now it works!

Comment: Instead of checking whole strings, you might just check on characters: `switch(userInput[0]) { case `A`: /*...*/ break; case `B`: /* ... */; default: /*...*/ break; }` Then you do the same on second character within every switch. If that's actually a nice solution might depend on the number of cases. Don't forget to include `case 0` for the strings that are terminated.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to change the order of the checks so that longer prefix comparisons come first. For example:

```
void parseUserInput(char *userInput)
{
    if (strncmp(userInput, "DNA", 3) == 0)
    {
        printf("Student has Special Situation : DNA (Did Not Attend)\n");
    }
    else if (strncmp(userInput, "D", 1) == 0)
    {
        printf(">> This input should be directed to the << assessGrade(char *) >> function ...\n");
        assessGrade(userInput);
    }
    else if (strncmp(userInput, "I/P", 3) == 0)
    {
        printf("Student has Special Situation : I/P (In Process)\n");
    }
    else if (strncmp(userInput, "I", 1) == 0)
    {
        printf("Student has Special Situation : I (Incomplete)\n");
    }
}
```